# PhoneGap Blackberry application

Tags: ios, cordova, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

i am building a small application using html5 and jquery mobile.
i need to run this on multiple platforms including android, iOS and blackberry.

i used phonegap to build my application successfully.
the apk for android is successfully installed in android device.
but i am not able to install application for black berry and iOS.

blackberry OTA downloads a jad file which is not working with my blackberry device.
i know there are COD files references in jad file that needs to download OTA.
but i am not able to run that.

how to install blackberry OTA?

similarly i need help for iOS?

and what are the licensing schemes for blackberry and iOS?

can i run the phonegap build for blackberry without license, if yes then how, if not then what should i do?

any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Too many questions, too little research in my opinion.  Look here for some answers regarding BB.  http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/.  Note that WebWorks 2 is BB10 only, make sure you look for Info on WebWorks 1

Comment: JAD files are for the BlackBerry 5.0, 6 and 7 devices (they ran a Java OS). Tutorial on how to install:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-to-Deploy-and-Distribute-Applications/ta-p/442794